# Parse and replace multiple variants using PowerShells regex

Tags: regex, powershell

Parsing a text document using the code below matches every instance of '333', however I would like only the three examples below to be changed.

```
(Get-Content input.json) | ForEach-Object {
    $_ -replace '333', '666'
} | Set-Content output.json
```

This should change:

- "se333" → "se666"
- "SE333" → "SE666"
- "333" → "666"

This should be left unchanged:

- "1212333" → unchanged
- "3331212" → unchanged
- "333asda" → unchanged
- "asd333" → unchanged

What is the PowerShell regex solution for this?

Comment: What do `"se333"` and `"asd333"` differ in? What is the rule here?  I thought `(?<!\P{L})333\b` will work (match `333` that is preceded with a letter or at the start of the string) and is followed with word boundary, but it also matches `asd333`.

Comment: "se333" is an ID so the "se" is part of the key, asd is supposed to represent any other letters. Good question!

Comment: Does  it mean the `se` is a static part that will nevery change? Then try `(?i)(?<=\bse|^)333\b` or [`(?i)(?<=\b(?:se)?)333\b`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fi%29%28%3f%3c%3d%5cb%28%3f%3ase%29%3f%29333%5cb&i=se333%0d%0aSE333%0d%0a333%0d%0aThis+should+be+left+unchanged%0d%0a%0d%0a%221212333%22+-%3e+unchanged%0d%0a%223331212%22+-%3e+unchanged%0d%0a%22333asda%22+-%3e+unchanged%0d%0a%22asd333%22+-%3e+unchanged&o=m). Or if there must be any 2 ASCII letters, use `(?i)(?<=\b(?:[a-z]{2})?)333\b`

Comment: Yes exactly, `se` is static, it looks promising, do I just swap `333` in my code snippet to `(?i)(?<=\bse|^)333\b` verbatim?

Comment: `$_ -replace '(?i)(?<=\b(?:se)?)333\b', '666'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
(?i)(?<=\b(?:se)?)333\b
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fi%29%28%3F%3C%3D%5Cb%28%3F%3Ase%29%3F%29333%5Cb&i=se333%0D%0ASE333%0D%0A333%0D%0AThis%20should%20be%20left%20unchanged%0D%0A%0D%0A%221212333%22%20-%3E%20unchanged%0D%0A%223331212%22%20-%3E%20unchanged%0D%0A%22333asda%22%20-%3E%20unchanged%0D%0A%22asd333%22%20-%3E%20unchanged&o=m)

**Details**

- `(?i)` - case insensitive modifier
- `(?<=\b(?:se)?)` - before `333` there must be a word boundary and anoptional substrin `se`
- `333` - a literal substring
- `\b` - a trailing word boundary.

Powershell test:

```
PS> $s = "se333 SE333 333 1212333 3331212 333asda asd333"
PS> $s -replace '(?i)(?<=\b(?:se)?)333\b', '666'
se666 SE666 666 1212333 3331212 333asda asd333
```